# Finite axiomatisation of an extension of $T$ complete w.r.t. Neighbourhood Semantics and incomplete w.r.t. Kripke

Tags: reference-request, modal-logic

A modal logic is normal if and only if $\Box (p \to q) \to (\Box p \to \Box q)$ is provable and the rules of modus ponens and necessitation holds.

Let $T$ be a smallest normal modal logic in which $\Box p\to p$ is provable.

I his [paper of 1975](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02121664) Martin Serastian Gerson conjectures that if $L$ is a modal propositional logic which is an extension of $T$ and which is complete with respect to the Neighbourhood Semantics but incomplete with respect to the Relational Semantics then $L$ is not finitely
axiomatizable.

Does this conjecture have any furter development (proof/disproof) in the literature?